# Trying to filter database using flask sqlalchemy that matches two fields but comes across key error

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm new to flask and have been trying to filter my database(using the fields age and town). I'm getting type error which i assume is because of the fields integer and string and i'm stuck on how to resolve it. Here's my route code:

```
@app.route("/search/<string:town>/<int:age>", methods = ["GET"])
def search(town, age):
        search_result = User.query.filter(User.town.like('%'+town+'%'),User.age.like('%'+age+'%')) 
        Serializer = UserSchema(many = True)
        data = Serializer.dump(search_result)

        return jsonify(data), 200
```

i get this error which is pretty self explanatory.

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not &quot;int&quot;) to str //
```

Any help or workaround on how to filter my database using both the integer and string values passed in my endpoint route?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide more details on the error and hopefully it is clear enough

Comment: If age is an integer then it isn't possible to use it in a `LIKE` query.  You must use mathematical inequalities like equals, not equals, greater than, less than etc.

Comment: I did as you said and it works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your variable `age` is an integer: your code probably fails on `'%'+age+'%'` since it cannot concatenate the integer `age` with the strings `'%'`.

One possible solution can be to use `.format()`: `User.age.like("%{}%".format(age))`.

Does that solve the error for you?

EDIT: Since your input will be a string, you might also need to convert your database column values to a string in order to make this work, this would result in the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, String

cast(User, String).age.like("%{}%".format(age))
```

Comment: I'll try to change the column value to string but was curious to perform further search operations ie query from age 12 to 15 from town z which i think only works with integers. But changing the column value will work in the meantime.

Comment: The `LIKE` query on a string starting and ending with `'%'` is used to find all strings that contain your input string (in this case age). That means that if your age is "5", it will also return queries where age is "15", "325", etc. 

If you want to search in integer ranges, you'll need to replace the `LIKE` query like @snakecharmerb suggests and in that case, my solution is not required anymore, since you won't deal with strings anymore

Comment: I replaced the LIKE query and the code worked. Thanks for your helpful comment.